# Trying to identify large WWII aircraft by aileron position on rudder

Tags: airplane

So I have this artifact, a man's slide-on tie clip with the figure of a large, overwing, possibly four engine aircraft, with possible pontoons. Any idea what this baby is? It looks like a Pan Am Clipper, but the position of the aileron, midway up the rudder, has my search skills stumped so far. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Can you post a picture of the clip?

Comment: The aileron is midway up the rudder? Do you mean the horizontal stabilizer (or tailplane) is midway up the vertical stabilizer (or tail fin)? Ailerons are way out by the wingtips; they're nowhere near the tail, where the rudder is.

Comment: Please try to fix the question to address the incorrect use of "aileron".  A photo of the artifact would also be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The Boeing 314 Clipper had a very distinctive triple tail, but it also had (what appears to be) a trim tab half way up the rudders, so maybe that's it?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

The PBY-5A has retractable wing tip “pontoons”, and meets all you criteria except “possible four engine”.

It is possible that the tie clip is just a generic representation of a flying boat, and may not represent an actual aircraft.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Spruce Goose, maybe?

[image: Spruce Goose]

[Wikipedia: Hughes H-4 Hercules](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hughes_H-4_Hercules)

It's not exactly WWII, but close, first (and only) flight was in 1947.

P.S. I guess by aileron you mean elevator ;)